# getResources for ModX Evolution?

Tags: php, content-management-system, modx

Does anyone know if getResources works for ModX Evolution? I've been trying to get it working for a while now with no success.

If there is no way to get it working, does anyone know of an equivalent way to get multiple resources to show on the one page (with their templates as well)?

Many thanks

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`58` &sortdir=`ASC` &sortby=`menuindex` &limit=`100` &includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1` &tpl=`eventtemp` ]]
```

Comment: Yes it absolutely does, will need to see your code.

Comment: @SeanKimball thanks Sean. Code Added above. I think one of my main issues is how to go about it - Do I create a template as normal, create my resources and then add the above into the 'parent' resource?

Comment: your code certainly looks right, if you have resources above 58 then it should be returning something. remove the &tpl attribute & it will basically dump an array of its results. and show nothing if there were none.

Comment: Oops! sorry, I actually meant EVOLUTION - I am updating the question

Comment: ok - yea ... no experience with Evo. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replicate this using [Ditto](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Ditto) in Evolution - the snippet call would be something like:

```
[!Ditto? &parents=`58` &orderBy=`menuindex ASC` &display=`100` &tpl=`eventtemp`!]
```

100 is quite a lot of resources to list on one page though. The query might be a bit slow, are you sure you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it worked fine for me

```
<a href="[~61~]" title="[!Ditto? &documents=`61` &tpl=`@CODE [+pagetitle+]`!]">a link text</a>
```